# dojo.io.iframe and download of Excel/PDF

Tags: javascript, dojo, io

I would like to use a Dojo button to download an Excel or a PDF file. So far I've managed to do it by using a call to `dojo.io.iframe` in the `onClick` handler of the button. However, this will only download the file once. Any successive calls will be ignored.

This is the call:

```
function exportToExcel() {
    dojo.io.iframe.send({
        url: '/report/export',
        handleAs: 'xml',
        content: {
            __export: 'excel'
        }
    });
}
```

As if the `dojo.io.iframe` does not consider the previous request to be completed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `dojo.io.iframe.send`, then the response should be in certain format to tell dojo that the request is completed. The response should be wrapped in the `<textarea>` element of a HTML document. As in your case, the response is a binary stream, so dojo didn't know whether the request is completed. If you didn't specify a `timeout`, dojo will wait forever.

To achieve the task, you can use following approach:

```
var downloadPdfIframeName = "downloadPdfIframe"; 
var iframe = dojo.io.iframe.create(downloadPdfIframeName);
dojo.io.iframe.setSrc(iframe, url, true);
```

Comment: This works very well.  Just remember to add a blank.html to your root, and point djConfig.dojoBlankHtmlUrl = "./blank.html".

Comment: blank.html is not required in dojo 1.7.2, I just tested it ; )

Comment: with this approach how to check if file is there in the response or not with callback ??

Comment: Works beautifully!. i had no idea how to fix this download problem. works in ie 9,,10,11, chrome firefox.